# Child age for Virgin Atlantic flights

Tags: air-travel, tickets, children, fares

My son was born September 2007. For a flight from India to the USA on Virgin Atlantic, will he be issued a child ticket fare?

Comment: What did Virgin Atlantic say about this when you asked them?

Comment: Is the trip before his birthday? https://www.virginatlantic.com/us/en/travel-information/special-flight-requirements/flying-with-children.html

Comment: Call the airline. They will provide the best answer.

Comment: i called up airlines instead of calculating current age on given date of birth , they were insiisting i give them childs age

Answer (score 3):

Typically the child needs to meet the age condition the time of boarding. If your son is not 12 yet on the day of your return flights, you can buy a child ticket. Otherwise you need to go with a young adult ticket.

Things are more complicated if the critical birthday happens during the travel. In this case you should contact the airline directly and ask for advise.

There doesn't seem to be much of a price difference, so I don't think it may be safer to just go with young adult.

Comment: travel date between  9 may 2019 to 21 may 2019